# Extracting data from Yahoo! Finance using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance, stock-data

I am currently trying to create a stock information script. However, I am only able to retrieve the data from the initial page of the stocks, and not the key statistics page. This is the page I am trying to obtain data from:
https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TICKER/key-statistics?p=TICKER

Here is the code that I am using: (mostly from a video I watched)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import xlsxwriter
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


key_stats_on_main =['Market cap', 'PE ratio (TTM)', 'EPS (TTM)']
key_stats_on_stat =['Enterprise value', 'Trailing P/E', 'Forward P/E',
                     'PEG Ratio (5-yr expected)', 'Return on assets', 'Quarterly revenue growth (yoy)',
                     'EBITDA', 'Diluted EPS (ttm)', 'Total debt/equity (mrq)', 'Current ratio (mrq)']

stocks_arr =[]
pfolio_file= open("/Users/z_hutcho/Documents/Programming/yfinance/stocks.csv", "r")
for line in pfolio_file:
    indv_stock_arr = line.strip().split(',')
    stocks_arr.append(indv_stock_arr)

print(stocks_arr)

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=2560x1600")
chrome_driver = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
stock_info_arr = []

for stock in stocks_arr:
    stock_info = []
    ticker = stock[0]
    stock_info.append(ticker)

    url = "https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}?p={0}".format(ticker)
    url2 = "https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}/key-statistics?p={0}".format(ticker)

    browser.get(url)
    innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, 'html.parser')
    for stat in key_stats_on_main:
        page_stat1 = soup.find(text=stat)
        try:
            page_row1 = page_stat1.find_parent('tr')
            try:
                page_statnum1 = page_row1.find_all('span')[1].contents[1].get_text(strip=True)
                print(page_statnum1)
            except:
                page_statnum1 = page_row1.find_all('td')[1].contents[0].get_text(strip=True)
                print(page_statnum1)
        except:
            print('Invalid parent for this element')
            page_statnum1 = "N/A"

        stock_info.append(page_statnum1)

    browser.get(url2)
    innerHTML2 = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML2, 'html.parser')
    for stat in key_stats_on_stat:
        page_stat2 = soup2.find(text=stat)
        try:
            page_row2 = page_stat2.find_parent('tr')
            try:
                page_statnum2 = page_row2.find_all('span')[1].contents[1].get_text(strip=True)
                print(page_statnum2)
            except:
                page_statnum2 = page_row2.find_all('td')[1].contents[0].get_text(strip=True)
                print(page_statnum2)
        except:
            print('Invalid parent for this element')
            page_statnum2 = 'N/A'
        stock_info.append(page_statnum2)

    stock_info_arr.append(stock_info)

print(stock_info_arr)
```

The results from this are as follows for the stock ticker AAPL:

```
1.3T
24.52
11.89
Invalid parent for this element
Invalid parent for this element
Invalid parent for this element
Invalid parent for this element
Invalid parent for this element
Invalid parent for this element
Invalid parent for this element
Invalid parent for this element
Invalid parent for this element
Invalid parent for this element
```

Not too sure why the second page isn't being scraped correctly... I am not very experienced in beautiful soup. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: see python module [yahoo-finance](https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-finance/)

Comment: the main problem is that you use `except:` and you don't display expection whihc you get - `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` - so you don't know what is real problem

Comment: if something makes problem then you should display it - ie. using `print()` - and then you can see what can be wrong. So display `innerHTML` to see if you get correct page or HTML with warning for bots/scripts or captcha.

Comment: `Selenium` has `browser.page_source` and you don't have to use `execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")`

Comment: This from Aug 17 still works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57540063/6241235

Comment: Check out this python package:  [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery)