# Web Scraping Yahoo Finance Statistics - Code Errors Out on Empty Fields

Tags: python, json, dictionary, web-scraping

I found this useful code snippet:
[Web scraping of Yahoo Finance statistics using BS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57538976/web-scraping-of-yahoo-finance-statistics-using-bs4)

I have simplified the code as per the block below:

```
import requests, re, json, pprint

p = re.compile(r'root\.App\.main = (.*);')
# tickers = ['NKE']
tickers = ['AGL.AX']
results = {}

with requests.Session() as s:

    for ticker in tickers:
        r = s.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/key-statistics?p={}'.format(ticker,ticker))
        data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
        #print(data)
        key_stats = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']
        print(key_stats)
        res = {
                'Enterprise Value' : key_stats['defaultKeyStatistics']['enterpriseValue']['fmt']
                ,'Shares_Short' : key_stats['defaultKeyStatistics']['sharesShort']['longFmt']
        }
        results[ticker] = res

pprint.pprint(results)
```

If the output has valid data (eg, Enterprise value), the key_stats dictionary will contain data as per below, and the code will spit out the output without a problem.

```
'enterpriseValue': {'raw': 13684141056, 'fmt': '13.68B', 'longFmt': '13,684,141,056'},
```

However, some elements are basically empty. For example, the Australian Securities Exchange doesn't publish Short Share data. So the entry in the key_stats dictionary looks like this.

'sharesShort': {},

Whenever the code comes against something like the above, it errors out with a message similar to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Scan_Yahoo_Stats_Page.py", line 35, in <module>
    ,'Shares_Short' : key_stats['defaultKeyStatistics']['sharesShort']['longFmt'
]
KeyError: 'longFmt'
```

I'd like the code to give this data a value of "N/A" whenever this situation occurs. Is there a way that this can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the get method for dictionaries, which allows you to supply a default value in the event a key is not found:

```
key_stats['defaultKeyStatistics']['sharesShort'].get(‘longFmt’, ‘N/A’)
```